# Is there a way to auto-match multiple parameters the same?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I have multiple deep neural networks in my model and want them to have the same input sizes
(networks are of different classes). For example, my model is:

```py
class Model:
 def __init__(self, cfg: DictConfig):
   self.net1 = Net1(**cfg.net1_hparams)
   self.net2 = Net2(**cfg.net2_hparams)
```

Here, Net1 and Net2 have different sets of hyper parameters, but among which the `input_size` parameter is shared between Net1 and Net2, and have to be matched, i.e.,  `cfg.net1_hparams.input_size == cfg.net2_hparams.input_size`.

I could define the input_size at the parent level: `cfg.input_size` and manually pass them to both Net1 and Net2. But, I want the hparams-configs of each Net's are **complete** so that later I can build Net1 only using the `cfg.net1_hparams`.

Is there a good way to achieve this in hydra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using OmegaConf's [variable interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.0_branch/usage.html#variable-interpolation) feature.

Here is a minimal example using variable interpolation with Hydra to achieve the desired result:

```yaml
# config.yaml
shared_hparams:
  input_size: [128, 128]
net1_hparams:
  name: net one
  input_size: ${shared_hparams.input_size}
net2_hparams:
  name: net two
  input_size: ${shared_hparams.input_size}
```

```py
"""my_app.py"""
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig

class Model:
    def __init__(self, cfg: DictConfig):
        print("Net1", dict(**cfg.net1_hparams))
        print("Net2", dict(**cfg.net2_hparams))

@hydra.main(config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    Model(cfg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_app()
```

Running `my_app.py` at the command line produces this result:

```sh
$ python my_app.py
Net1 {'name': 'net one', 'input_size': [128, 128]}
Net2 {'name': 'net two', 'input_size': [128, 128]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Quick question. While the above code works well, when I print the cfg by `OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg)`, I see non-interpolated results for input_size: `input_size: ${shared_hparams.input_size}`. Do you think this is the expected behavior?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, that is expected: by default, `OmegaConf.to_yaml` does not resolve interpolations. Try using the `resolve` keyword argument: `OmegaConf.to_yaml(cfg, resolve=True)`. Also of interest to you may be `OmegaConf.to_container(cfg, resolve=True)`, which will convert the `DictConfig` object to a plain Python `dict`.